# How do I configure GCP monitoring policy documentation in Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We have a monitoring alert policy in GCP which we configured in Terraform. We also want to create a documentation using Terraform.

We are creating documentation using following command in GCP.

```
gcloud alpha monitoring policies update projects/project_name/alertPolicies/5861347861929375791 \
--documentation-format="text/markdown" \
--documentation="API has exceeded its quota limit. The systems load has increased beyond capacity, consider increasing your Global and Regional quotas. If this is unexpected behaviour, validate that this is not a bug within your platform."
```

Is there any way we can create the same in Terraform?

Configuration for Monitoring Policy:

```
# Alerts when API seeing errors
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "dlp_api_see_errors" {
  project      = PROJECT_NAME
  display_name = "API is seeing errors"
  combiner     = "OR"
  
  conditions {
    display_name = "API is seeing errors"

    condition_threshold {
      filter          = "metric.type=\"serviceruntime.googleapis.com/api/request_count\" resource.type=\"consumed_api\" metric.label.\"response_code\"!=\"200\" resource.label.\"service\"=\"dlp.googleapis.com\""
      duration        = "60s"
      comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
      aggregations {
        alignment_period     = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_SUM"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
      }

      trigger {
        count   = 1
      }
    }
  }

  notification_channels = "${concat(google_monitoring_notification_channel.ndw_alerting_email.*.id, google_monitoring_notification_channel.ndw_alerting_phone.*.id)}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`google_monitoring_alert_policy` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/monitoring_alert_policy.html) has the [`documentation` block parameter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/monitoring_alert_policy.html#documentation) which allows you to set Markdown documentation for the alert.

Your resource should then look like the following:

```
# Alerts when API seeing errors
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "dlp_api_see_errors" {
  project      = PROJECT_NAME
  display_name = "API is seeing errors"
  combiner     = "OR"
  
  conditions {
    display_name = "API is seeing errors"

    condition_threshold {
      filter          = "metric.type=\"serviceruntime.googleapis.com/api/request_count\" resource.type=\"consumed_api\" metric.label.\"response_code\"!=\"200\" resource.label.\"service\"=\"dlp.googleapis.com\""
      duration        = "60s"
      comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
      aggregations {
        alignment_period     = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_SUM"
        cross_series_reducer = "REDUCE_SUM"
      }

      trigger {
        count   = 1
      }
    }
  }

  notification_channels = "${concat(google_monitoring_notification_channel.ndw_alerting_email.*.id, google_monitoring_notification_channel.ndw_alerting_phone.*.id)}"

  documentation {
    mime_type = "text/markdown"
    content   = "API has exceeded its quota limit. The systems load has increased beyond capacity, consider increasing your Global and Regional quotas. If this is unexpected behaviour, validate that this is not a bug within your platform."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Terraform to create/update ["documentation block"](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/monitoring_alert_policy.html#documentation) with some limitations.**

> The `documentation` block supports:
>
> `content` - (Optional) The text of the documentation, interpreted
> according to mimeType. The content may not exceed 8,192 Unicode
> characters and may not exceed more than 10,240 bytes when encoded in
> UTF-8 format, whichever is smaller.
>
> `mime_type` - (Optional) The format of the content field. Presently,
> only the value "text/markdown" is supported.

You can however use "mime/text" format and include all the information directly.

Also it may be usefull to have a look at [GCP's official documentation regarding `documentation` block](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#documentation) in this feature but loading content from external file is also not documented there.

Only mention about this feature in the official docs is in [Modyfying Policy's Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-api#api-doc-policy).

But since you can do it with `gcloud alpha` then I'd play around with Terraform and maybe you will find a solution how to put "file" type in the documentation block...